# Laravel undefined variable (but it is sent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

My `PostController`:

```
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                 ->where([['status', 'PUBLISHED'],['post_type', 'PORTFOLIO']])
                 ->paginate(9);

    $partners = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                 ->where([['status', 'PUBLISHED'],['post_type', 'PARTNERS']])
                 ->get();
 //   return view('landing.onepageindex', ['posts' => $posts], ['pages' => $pages], ['partners' => $partners]);
    return view(
             'landing.onepageindex',
             ['posts' => $posts],
             ['pages' => $pages],
             ['partners' => $partners]
         );
```

I'm trying to do a foreach for the partners var, but it says its undefined, what am I doing wrong here? I'm rather new to Laravel, but this thing just got me confused. Am I not allowed to create 2 vars that go for the same post (just different post types)?

Posts and Pages work as they should, partners doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your data in second parameter to view

```
return view(
        'landing.onepageindex',
        ['posts' => $posts, 'pages' => $pages, 'partners' => $partners]
);
```

Comment: I literally have no idea why i started passing them separate, anyway, your answer works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider using the `compact()` function for brevity. `return view('index',compact('posts','pages','partners'));`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Inside view function, first parameter is view path and second parameter is array of data which we pass in view.

```
return view(
    'landing.onepageindex',
    ['posts' => $posts, 'pages' => $pages, 'partners' => $partners]
);
```

OR

```
return view(
    'landing.onepageindex',
    compact('posts','pages','partners')
);
```